# App installation failed. This operation is unsupported

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I've been updating an app that works perfectly in iOS7 to be compatible with the new iOS8. I can't deploy the app to an iPhone with the last GM iOS8 version. The compilation process give me no errors, but Xcode give me the following alert:

App installation failed. This operation is unsupported.

[image: Xcode error]

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem too. The environment I used is *Xcode6* and try to run my app on *iOS8* devices.

My solution is

1. first change **Deployment Location** as **NO** in your **Build Settings**.
2. Close Xcode
3. Remove all intermediate build files located in the corresponding subfolders (has your app prefix) under Xcode Derived Data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/).
4. Restart your Xcode, build, and then run app on your devices.

Comment: I believe Xcode 6 might have some bugs or issues to run app on iOS8 devices. Hopefully they will have patch to Xcode soon.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

This is a compatibility problem between Xcode 6 and your app configuration.

1) Download Xcode 5 and try to run your app on your ios8 device, it should work

2) Try to recreate your app configuration from scratch to ensure compatibility with Xcode 6